# Android + MySQL: Notify users when a new message is received

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, notifications

Hi I've been working on a project where a user receives a message coming from a mySQL database online.  I'm using smarterASP.net as a temporary online server and i already found a way how to read data from my database.and i have to notify them "how many new messages they have received" automatically. Is there a way how to do it? like when there is change in number of data inside my database.

and i've considered using GCM to notify my users.

Not a SMS type messaging by the way

Feel free to comment any ideas on how could i do it. Thanks

Comment: You can use Firebase or other push notification for that. send user's message in push and notify for the New message received.

Comment: @RajeshNasit using Firebase is a bit tricky sir, every time the admin send a message, the admin also will send a notification to the users, one by one or selected users only.

Comment: you can manage at admin panel. if you want to send message to all or selected users. both options are available